# Remove Linked List Elements

Tags: python, linked-list

I have defined curr before starting the loop, so why it is throwing me an error: "NoneType object has no attribute 'next. "?

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
        curr = head
        while curr:
            if head.val != curr.val: #if searching val is not first val of list
                if curr.val == val:
                    prev.next = curr.next
                    # curr = temp.next
            else:                         # if seraching val is first val of list
                temp = curr
                curr.next = None
                curr = temp.next
            prev = curr
            curr = curr.next # this line is getting error
        return head
```

Comment: This line `curr = curr.next`, must be - `curr = next(curr)`.

Comment: temp.next is None and you have curr = temp.next in else part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because when the `else` block gets executed, you make `curr` equal to `None`, because you set `temp.next = None` and made `curr` equal to `temp`:

```
else:
    temp = curr
    curr.next = None # This sets `temp.next` to `None` as `temp == curr`
    curr = temp.next  # ...so now `curr` is None
# ...
curr = curr.next # ...and then this line will raise an exception...
```

Some other comments on your code:

- With `head.val != curr.val` you assume that all values in the list are unique. If this is not the case, you might get a false negative here. You should just compare the *references*: `head != curr`. However, I would instead suggest to perform a separate loop to deal with the case where the `head` node needs to be removed.
- Your code never updates `head`. Yet when the current `head` matches the value (i.e. the `else` case), you should actually update `head` with `head = head.next`.

Here is your code corrected:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
        # You can deal with the boundary case in a separate loop
        while head:
            if head.val == val:
                head = head.next
        if head:
            # Now let prev follow behind curr
            prev = head
            curr = head.next
            while curr:
                if curr.val == val:
                    prev.next = curr.next
                    curr.next = None
                else:
                    prev = curr
                curr = prev.next
        return head
```